# Combining two raster layers with ArcGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

So I am trying to join/merge two raster layers that have values of either 1 or 0. I am using the following command in in ArcGIS Raster Calculator:

```
Con(("urban" == 1) | ("mixed" == 1), 1, 0)
```

The new raster layer is missing cells from the "urban" raster layer, I have no idea why this is happening.

I have also tried the following commands with the same result:

```
("urban" == 1) | ("mixed" == 1)
```

or

removing all the cells equal to 0 in both layers and then:

```
"urban" + "mixed"
```

Comment: Did you try to use " & "  instead of " | " for combining the conditions?

Comment: I have tried that, a get a raster layer with cells only equal to 0. The cells that are equal to 1 in both layers are not overlapping, so there are no cases where both conditions are true, hence I am using "|"

Comment: Have you tried simply adding the two rasters "urban" + "mixed" without removing the 0 cells? You'll end up with 0+1, 1+0 or 0+0. The result will be grid with 1s and 0s since urban and mixed are mutually exclusive. Removing 0s may be causing you trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for your case:

```
Out_Raster = SetNull((Abs(IsNull("urban")-1)+Abs(IsNull("mixed")-1))<1,(Abs(IsNull("urban")-1)+Abs(IsNull("mixed")-1)))
```

Here is a part by part explanation:

- `IsNull("urban")` returns 0 for data values and 1 for nulls.
- `Abs(IsNull("urban")-1)`  will make nulls into 0 and other cells into 1 by subtracting 1 and taking absolute value.
- `(Abs(IsNull("urban")-1)+Abs(IsNull("mixed")-1))` Compiles all 1 values from both datasets.
- I then feed this ugly expression `(UGLY_EXP)` into a `SetNull(UGLY_EXP<1,UGLY_EXP)` to set all the 0 values to null and other cells to 1.